# Can't get the bootstrap dropdown working in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a dropdown in my ASP.NET Core Application.

The code for my dropdown origintes directly from [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/):

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

But all i get is a button with the dropdown arrow that isn't working at all.

I tried following the solution provided in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280538/how-to-install-popper-in-visual-studio-2019-locally), but that also didn't work.
[The button in its current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5FdF.png)

I am using the default stylesheets and javascripts, which should be enough according to [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/):

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - HellBotWebUI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/HellBotWebUI.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
```

```html
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Comment: If you open up the F12 console in the browser are you getting any javascript errors or missing file references? For some reason, bundling in asp.net is a very confusing dark art.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `Bootstrap 4 `and not the latest version which is [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/)? ASP.NET Core templates have Bootstrap `v5.1.0` included by default.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid no i don't seem to get any errors or anything like that.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos you are right, it is using Bootstrap v5.1.0 and with the code for this version it started working. I was mislead by some earlier tutorials claiming it was using v4 by default and now i'm feeling kinda stupid. If you want to make this comment an answer i can mark it as solved.

Comment: Put id="navbarDropdown" on Button and <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">, use ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core web application templates use Bootstrap `v5.1.0` by default so you need to look at the newer [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/).